# NotFoundError: DOM Exception 8 when substituting innerHTML

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events, innerhtml

I'm new to js-development. I have the following code:

```
<html>
<body>

<div><span id="inline">Click here to start editing</span></div>

<script>
    var inline = document.getElementById("inline");     
    inline.onclick = function() {           
        if (!inline.editable) {
            var text = inline.innerText;
            inline.innerHTML = "<input type='text' id='inline-editable'>";
            inline.editable = true;
            var inline_editable = document.getElementById("inline-editable");
            inline_editable.value = text;

            inline_editable.onblur = function() {
                var value = inline_editable.value;                  
                inline.editable = false;
                inline.innerHTML = value;
            }

            inline_editable.onkeypress = function(event) {
                if (event.keyCode == 13) {
                    inline_editable.onblur();
                }
            }               
        }
    }
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Which shows some text inside `span` and allows inline editing. When I finish editing within just `onblur` event it work perfectly fine. But if I want to terminate editing by Enter and use the same hander I get an error `NotFoundError: DOM Exception 8` in this line:

```
inline.innerHTML = value;
```

Nevertheless everything works as I expect. Can anyone help me to avoid this error?

I assume that is happened because I destroy `inline-editable` element while event handling is not finished and it wants to invoke `onchange` maybe. Should I have 2 controls all the time an switch their visibility instead?

Comment: no it shouldn't, HTML5 is not XML. You can use self-closed tag withou the trailing /.

Comment: @KhanhTO that is not going to make any difference!

Comment: Well just a quick debug, the onblur gets triggered twice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem here is the onblur is triggered twice, the second time, the element is not there which causes the problem. Kill the events

```
var inline = document.getElementById("inline");     
inline.onclick = function() {

    if (!inline.editable) {
        var text = inline.innerText;
        inline.innerHTML = "<input type='text' id='inline-editable'>";
        inline.editable = true;
        var inline_editable = document.getElementById("inline-editable");
        inline_editable.value = text;

        inline_editable.onblur = function() {
            this.onblur = function(){};
            var value = this.value;
            inline.editable = false;
            inline.innerHTML = value;
        }

        inline_editable.onkeypress = function(event) {
            if (event.keyCode == 13) {
                this.onblur();                    
            }
        }               
    }
}
```